# jQuery - event parameter vs this?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I was browsing some ideas for wizard step forms I found the below code and spotted the usage of event parameter `e` as well as `$(this)`.

From my understanding `$(this)` also has event object information 
but since `e` is the parameter used in this example, why not use `e` throughout the code block instead of `this`?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var parent = $(this).parent('div'), grandpa = $('.steps-content>div'), index = grandpa.index(parent)+1;
        parent.removeClass('content-active');
        grandpa.eq(index).addClass('content-active');
$('.steps-wizard').children('div').removeClass('step-active').eq(index).addClass('step-active');
    });
});
```

Comment: `this == e.target`, `this` has no event information

Comment: @Bergi Thanks. So you can use e.target instead of $('this')?
Although the correct syntax might be `e.target` it makes more sense to me if it was something like e.origin

Comment: Yes, you could use `$(e.target)` as well but it's longer, unconventional and possibly slower. I don't know why `origin` (the mouse, the user?) would make more sense to you, but [the `Event` interface is standardized](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-interfaces).

Answer (score 0):

In this example `e` is used in

```
e.preventDefault();
```

which is used to prevent the link default's action, that is leading the browser to another page.

That's something that can't be done using just `this`.

Answer (score 0):

`e.target` is `this`. `e` also has other methods and propertes. See [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) for further details of the jquery event object